# Tooltip is not displaying in MDIChild Form

Tags: winforms, tooltip, mdichild, mdiparent, gridcontrol

I am using devexpress gridcontrol in my desktop application. But I am facing a problem with `tooltip`.I used the `repositoryHyperlinkbutton` and it has `3 buttons` in it named `view, edit, insert`

Now I want to display a tooltip for that three Buttons. I already set the property for it.When I use single form the Tooltip work fine. but when I used that form with MdiParent at that time the Tooltip is not display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Problem is solved in above the `devexpress 11.5` controls.
I done it.

Answer (score -1):

The cells in a GridView contains no controls - they are only painted. When you click a cell, its in-place editor is created (or - in this case - the 3 image buttons). No controls = no tooltips!

Comment: Then what is the solution for it ?

Comment: Add one column for each button and try the code from [this example](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E714).